# Find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\bigg ( \lim\limits_{x \to 0}(1 + \tan^2(x) + \tan^2(2x) + ... + \tan^2(nx))^\frac{1}{n^3x^2} \bigg )$.

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the following limit to find:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\bigg ( \lim\limits_{x \to 0}(1 + \tan^2(x) + \tan^2(2x) + ... + \tan^2(nx))^\frac{1}{n^3x^2} \bigg )$$

I've never done a double limit before so I have no idea as to how to approach this.

Comment: Forget about the outer limit at first and compute the inner limit. The parentheses indicate that is what should be computed first. To compute the inner limit write it as $[(1+\square)^{1/\square}]^{\square/(n^3x^2)}$, where $\square$ is that sum of $\tan$'s.  Since $\square\to0$ then $(1+\square)^{1/\square}\to e$. Then you need to compute the limit of $\square/(n^3x^2)$. Now, $\tan(ax)/x=a\tan(ax)/(ax)\to a$. Therefore this limit is $(1^2+2^2+...+n^2)/n^3$. Therefore, the inner limit is $\exp((1^2+2^2+...+n^2)/n^3)$.

Comment: You can now sum that sum in the exponent and take the outer limit.

Comment: @conditionalMethod I like how you post all your answers as a comment 

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I only care about using the website as a question-answer website and not the rest of the games that people play here.

Comment: @conditionalMethod I have full respect for that :D